# How to display user location on osmdroid mapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid, userlocation

I'm creating a GPS like application with omsdroid, I successfully displayed a map and centered it on the user location, but I can't find a way to display an "user icon" on the map.

I'm new on android (started like one week ago) so please explain all step and add sample of code if you can, thanks.

edit :

here is my code so far :

```
edit :
```

here is my code so far :

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    altitude = location.getAltitude();
    accuracy = location.getAccuracy();

    GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint( (latitude ),  (longitude ));

    myMapController.animateTo(p);
    myMapController.setCenter(p);

    mylocation = new MyLocationNewOverlay(new GpsMyLocationProvider(getApplicationContext()), mapView);

    mylocation.enableMyLocation();
    //mylocation.enableFollowLocation();
    mapView.getOverlays().add(mylocation);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For enable user location icon you should add the `MyLocationOverlay` on your map:

```
org.osmdroid.views.MapView openMapView = (org.osmdroid.views.MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.openmapview);

MyLocationOverlay myLocationoverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(getActivity(), openMapView);
myLocationoverlay.enableMyLocation();

mMapView.getOverlays().add(mMyLocationNewOverlay);
```

Comment: it worked fine on the emulator but when i launch it on my device the overlay don't show up, i used MyLocationNewOverlay because MyLocationOverlay was not working.